# How is the obamacare tax credit calculated?

Tags: taxes, healthcare, tax-credit, premiums

In the first 9 months of this year I had a relatively high income. However, I have no income since October. I used to have health insurance from my employer but now I am trying to get health insurance on the obamacare website (washington state) for the rest of the year (2 months).

Based on the website I qualify for tax credit to lower my health insurance premiums - as currently I have no income. That doesn't look right to me.

My question is whether I qualify for the tax credits for the months of November and December or not. I mean is the tax credit based on my yearly income including the months I worked or is calculated on a month-to-month basis.

In short: Currently I have zero income but I'll report a high income on my yearly tax return. Do I qualify for obamacare tax credits to lower my premiums for the months of no income?

Comment: What did you enter on the website for it to think you qualify for subsidy? When they ask for current income - they ask for the income for the **current year**, not that specific day.

Answer (score 4):

Your "relatively high" income will likely keep you from getting a subsidy. 
To be sure, there's a [calculator](http://kff.org/interactive/subsidy-calculator/) that will help you. For most tax related issues, it's the year's total that matters. If you made $90K in 6 months or even two weeks, that's income in 2015.